# Oracle Database 21C XE installation error

Tags: oracle21c

I am trying to install #Oracle #database XE and I am getting an error :

> {IDS_OracleConfigDlg_DatabaseConfigFailedMsg} An error occurred while
> configuring Oracle XE database. Check the logs at
> C:\app\gn1411\product\21c\cfgtoollogs\dbca and try again.

I would like to share the log with someone who can help

Comment: I am having the same problem, how did you solve yours

Comment: Unable to check available memory => had to delete old oracle windows services that had not been uninstalled successfully.

Answer (score 0):

For me (Windows 11) i have :

1. Uninstall the version of Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (which was the last version)
2. Install the version that in installer folder oracle (ISSetupPrerequisites/{8AD2FD1D-5968-4AD0-95CA-A6CF96F331FE}/vcredist_x64.exe)
3. In installer folder oracle execute "setup.exe" pour l'installation

Comment: This did not fixed my issue ;-(